# Update em 2mil registros <Clientes> como fazer um único update ao invés de 2k em separado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma Model de clientes e preciso fazer um update em `EnviadoEmailCobranca para 0`

Estou fazendo assim:

```
    var clientes = db.Clientes.Where(w => w.Status == 4);

    foreach (var item in clientes)
    {
        item.EnviadoEmailCobranca = false;

        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Porém isso é meio *burro*, pois estou fazendo 2mil updates em separado.
Existe algo como:

```
Update tabela_Clientes where EnviadoEmailCobranca=0 where Status =4
```

**Não queria fazer assim:**

```
var SQL = "Update tabela_Clientes where EnviadoEmailCobranca=0 where Status =4";
dbMailEnable.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SQL);
```

Comment: até tirei,mas o desempenho foi longe de ser razoável.. fiz um teste com 6mil registros e demorou bem mais que fazendo direto um ExecuteSQLCommand...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Como fazer um único update ao invés de 2k em separado?

Não usando Entity Framework nativo. Simples assim. Ele não atende a este tipo de demanda que você tem.

[Já o EntityFramework.Extended atende](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#batch-update-and-delete), pois tem *batch update* implementado. [O pacote NuGet dele está aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/).

Uso:

```
db.Clientes
  .Where(w => w.Status == 4)
  .Update(w => new Cliente { EnviadoEmailCobranca = 0 });
```

Comment: show....valeu, até pq 2mil é um numero inicial podendo subir pra 5mil ou mais..